# Android studio Camera 2 save video in full screen

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am using the Camera2 API to record videos, I've used [this](https://github.com/googlearchive/android-Camera2Video) project as a reference, I managed to change my TextTure view to full screen but the video that I am saving is still not in full screen, how can I change the saved video to full screen as well?

[image]

[image]

you can see that when I play the video the video dimensions are the same as my preview, please help how can I save the video in the same perspective as my preview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I managed to solve the problem, the video was not full screen because the aspect ratio of the video is not the same as the aspect ratio of the screen, so all we have to do is fix the aspect ratio of the video make it match with that of the screen, we can do this by following the below code...

first of all, we need to FFmpeg, I am using [this](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg) library

then we can simply use this command

```
val displaySize = Point().apply {
    windowManager.defaultDisplay.getSize(this)
}

val screenR = displaySize.y.toFloat() / displaySize.x

val testCrop = FFmpeg.execute("-i $videoPath -y -filter:v crop=ih/$screenR:ih ${OutputPath}")

when (testCrop) {
     RETURN_CODE_SUCCESS -> {
         //successful
     }

     RETURN_CODE_CANCEL -> {
        //canceled
     }

     else -> {
        // failed
     }
```

> videoPath

is the path of the video that you want to edit (the video we want to make into a full screen)

> outputPath

is the location where we want to save our video at, keep in mind that we should include the name of the file as well, for example

> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/myAppName/files/result.mp4

also, keep in mind that 'result.mp4' should not exist because FFmpeg will create that file for us, if there was a file with that name then we will get an error or we should give permission to FFmpeg to overwrite that file.

lastly the

> crop=ih/$screenR:ih

is used to change the width of the video to a ratio that would match the screen (in my case I always want my video to be vertical so I only change the height of the video) but please be aware that I'm not 100% sure if it is always correct to crop the width...

Answer (score 0):

Try with this method:

```
private static Size fullScreenVideoSize(Size[] choices) {
    for (Size size : choices) {
        if (size.getWidth() == size.getHeight() * 4 / 3 && size.getWidth() <= 1080) {
            return size;
        }
    }
    return choices[choices.length - 1];
}
```

And you can implement it:

```
mVideoSize = chooseVideoSize(map.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class));
mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class), width, height, mVideoSize);

int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    mTextureView.setAspectRatio(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
} else {
    mTextureView.setAspectRatio(mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
}
```

Comment: I'm already doing that, as I mentioned I tried everything that was written inside the example above and I converted the preview texture to full screen but I was not able to convert the output file to full screen as well

Comment: @MoTahir my suggestion is, copy and paste the extract of code you want to check, no one going to check a repo

Comment: I know, I'm already applying the code that you wrote, that's how I managed to change the screen display to full screen. but that does not effect the outputfil